# About Paypal payment error

Tags: asp.net, paypal, payment

Good day all,

I am trying to add payment function (**Paypal**) to my website. I generated the code from **Paypal** and managed to put on my website. However, when I was trying to log in to my account as **customer** to make the payment. i got this error message:

> ***Sorry, we cant complete yur purchase at this timing. Please return to the merchant and choose another way to pay***

Any idea what the problem is and how to fix it? or if you all can suggest any other better payment function other than paypal for asp.net?

Thank you

Comment: show us your code

Comment: This can often happen when cookies / cache get messed up in your browser.  Try with a different, clean browser that you don't typically use and see if that helps.